# Error in 2º equation roots coding in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

Today I started coding equations and algebraic expressions using Fortran (I'm using gfortran in Debian(Parrot-home OS) and Geany).

The problem is, I code on the same way(or equal) to the mode I see on internet, and I get only a wrong root to x' and x''.

```
program equacao2grau
    real delta, a, b, c, x, x2
    complex sqrt
    print*, "This program calc 2º equations"
    print*, "Give the values 'A', 'B'e 'C'"
    read*, a         !Getting values
    read*, b         !       for
    read*, c         !resolution
    if (a /= 0) then          !if 'a' be different of 0
        delta = b**2 - 4*a    !do delta
    end if

    print*, delta = b**2 - 4*a*c

    if (a .EQ. 0) then
        stop
    end if
        if (delta .EQ. 0) then
            print*, "The value is", (-b / 2*a)
                stop
        end if
        if (delta .GT. 0) then
            print*, "The roots are", -b + sqrt(delta) / 2*a
            print*, "e", -b - sqrt(delta) / 2*a
            stop
        end if
end
```

I know, it is incomplete, but I'm demotivated with don't find any correct result.

Things I researched:

- https://www.cenapad.unicamp.br/servicos/treinamentos/apostilas/apostila_fortran90.pdf
- http://ftp.demec.ufpr.br/disciplinas/TM111/Arquivos_Infomatica/Fortran/fortran.html#_Toc467428016
- http://www.oc.nps.edu/~bird/oc3030_online/fortran/if/logicalif.html
- http://wwwp.fc.unesp.br/~lavarda/fc1/apo/fort_04.htm

Comment: Obs:I can't put any archive or the code correctly here, i don't know why.

Comment: Sorry admin, i don't know how to use it properly.

Comment: please read [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Ok, i will read.

Comment: It would also be great if you read [ask] and pass the [tour] if you have not.

Comment: I strongly recommend you use Implicit None in your codes, and also note you shouldn't declare the intrinsic function sqrt as complex - if you do anything at all it should be Intrinsic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing brackets in the expressions.

```
-b + sqrt(delta) / 2*a
```

Should be:

```
(-b + sqrt(delta)) / (2*a)
```

And same for the other roots.

*Edit*
Also, as pointed by @albert, you omitted `c` in the formula of delta.
Moreover, as said by @IanBush, the declaration of `complex sqrt` must be removed.
And always use `implicit none`.

Comment: And how about the missing `c` in  `delta = b**2 - 4*a` (though it is in the misleading print but wrong statement, it should have been `print *, "delta = ",delta`

Comment: Thanks guys, i finally made it!!